# BAT file: Read from text file and then do something

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am new to BAT/CMD programming.

I have a file called "CurrentDevice" at the file directory "C:\Custom_BATS\Audio_Swap\CurrentDevice.txt"

Inside this file it will either say "Speakers" or "Headphones".

I want my BAT file to open the text file and follow this pseudo code below

- If the text == "Speakers"
- nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "Headphones" 1
- replace the text to "Headphones"
- save and close file
- 
- Else if the text == "Headphones"
- nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "Speakers" 1
- replace the text to "Speakers"
- save and close file

I presume this is simple but i'm struggling with a lot of the jargon im finding online.

This is my code so far

```
"C:\Custom_BATS\Audio_Swap\CurrentDevice.txt" set /p text=

if "%var%"=="Headphones"
(
nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "Speakers" 1
"C:\Custom_BATS\Audio_Swap\CurrentDevice.txt" echo Speakers
)

else if "%var%"=="Speakers"
(
nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "Headphones" 1
"C:\Custom_BATS\Audio_Swap\CurrentDevice.txt" echo Headphones
)
```

Comment: use `<"C:\Custom_BATS\Audio_Swap\CurrentDevice.txt" set /p text=` to read the first line (your only one) to a variable. use `if` for comaparison, use `>"C:\Custom_BATS\Audio_Swap\CurrentDevice.txt" echo Headphones` to (over)write to the file. See [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) for a good explanation of all commands. Hack it together and edit your question with your code, should you still have problems.

Comment: As you are only toggling between two devices I think that you could either; write to the file only in one of your scenarios, (and just check for the existence of that file); use an empty file and just rename it to the the name of the currently set device, (check for its name instead of reading the contents); or store the information in a custom registry value, (and query that value); just create a `Speakers.cmd` and a `Headphones.cmd`, (and run the one you need as required); create a single `.cmd` file which takes a parameter, `H` or `S` then use `%1` to determine the device for setting.

Comment: @Stephan I will start with what you have said and see what i can do. Thanks

Comment: @Compo I am wanting to set it up to only use one batch file as i am using one keybind. Everything else you have said  i dont understand. Im really new to CMD/BATCH

Comment: Jamie, only one of the five options I provided in my comment suggested two batch files, of those my preference would be the last option, using two shortcuts each passing the required parameter.

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "text.1=Speakers"
set "text.0=Headphones"
if exist "%~dpn0.flag" (
set "text.0=%text.1%"
del /q "%~dpn0.flag"
) else type nul > "%~dpn0.flag"
nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "%text.0%" 1
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

very close:

```
<"C:\Custom_BATS\Audio_Swap\CurrentDevice.txt" set /p text=

if "%text%"=="Headphones" (
  nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "Speakers" 1
  >"C:\Custom_BATS\Audio_Swap\CurrentDevice.txt" echo Speakers
) else (
  nircmd setdefaultsounddevice "Headphones" 1
  >"C:\Custom_BATS\Audio_Swap\CurrentDevice.txt" echo Headphones
)
```

you just missed the redirection `<` and `>` and messed the `if` syntax a bit.